# Model mismatch error when posting form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a simple image upload site in which users will have the ability to post comments on the images uploaded to the site, whenever posting a comment I am given this error :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SilkMeme.Models.Meme'.

I know it has something to do with the model being defined at the top of my view being different to the one I am sending the post request to but I'm not entirely sure how to fix it

View

```
@model SilkMeme.Models.Meme
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Memes", new { id = Model.SilkId }))
{
    <label for="thought">Thoughts?</label>
    <input type="text" name="thought"/>
    <label for="rating">Rating?</label>
    <input name="rating" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Post Thoughts" />
}
<div class="thoughts">
    @foreach (var c in ViewBag.thoughts)
    {
        <p>- @c.ThoughtWords , @c.ThoughtRating / 10 meme</p>
    }
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    var thoughts = from comment in db.Thoughts where comment.SilkId == id select comment;
    ViewBag.thoughts = thoughts;
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Meme meme = db.Memes.Find(id);
    if (meme == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(meme);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Comment(int id)
{
    int thoughtid = (from m in db.Thoughts select m).OrderByDescending(e => e.ThoughtId).FirstOrDefault().ThoughtId + 1;
    if (Request["thought"].ToString() != "")
    {
        Thought thought = new Thought()
        {
            ThoughtId = thoughtid,
            SilkId = id,
            Meme = db.Memes.Find(id),
            ThoughtWords = Request["thought"],
            ThoughtRating = Int32.Parse(Request["rating"])
        };
        db.Thoughts.Add(thought);
    }
    return View("Details", new { id = id });
}
```

Comment: Side note: You really should be using the strongly typed HtmlHelpers to generate you view. You passing an existing instance of `Meme` to the view but its property values will never be displayed - use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m =>.m.SomeProperty)` etc. and then post back your model - `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Comment(Meme model)` so its all correctly bound.

Comment: And never create your `thoughtid` manually like that - it will fail as soon as you have multiple users creating your data. Use an auto-incremented field for the Key.

Answer (score 1):

This line.

```
return View("Details", new { id = id });
```

It is basically passing an anonymous object with Id property to your view which is strongly typed to `Meme` type and expects an object of `Meme` class.

If you save your data successfully, Ideally,you should do a redirect to the GET action (following **PRG** pattern)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Comment(int id)
{
    int thoughtid = (from m in db.Thoughts select m)
                      .OrderByDescending(e => e.ThoughtId).FirstOrDefault().ThoughtId + 1;
    if (Request["thought"].ToString() != "")
    {
        Thought thought = new Thought()
        {
            ThoughtId = thoughtid,
            SilkId = id,
            Meme = db.Memes.Find(id),
            ThoughtWords = Request["thought"],
            ThoughtRating = Int32.Parse(Request["rating"])
        };
        db.Thoughts.Add(thought);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { Id=id });
}
```

Also, I recommend using MVC Modelbinding to read the submitted form data. You will find a ton of examples on stackoverflow to do that. When using ModelBinding, you can return the posted view model back to the view (with an error message if needed) and the ValidationSummary /ValidationMessgeFor helper methods can show an error message to user as needed.